# Hat manufacturing company and maximizing $z=8y_1+5y_2$

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

A hat manufacturing company produces two types of hats. The time required to produce the first type of hat is twice the time required to produce the second type. If all the hats are only of the second type, the company can produce a total of $500$ hats per day. The maximum daily sales of the first and second hats are $150$ and $250$, respectively.

Suppose the profit from the sale of the first and second type of hats is $8$ and $5$ dollars, respectively. It is desirable to determine the number of hats that should be produced from the first and second types to optimize the total profit.

---

**The answer is given by:**

Define $ x_i $ as the number of hats produced of the $i$th type,$ y_i $ as the number of daily sales of hats of the $i$th type, and $c_i$ as the time required to produce a hat of the $i$th type, then we want to maximize $$z=8y_1+5y_2$$ subject to :

$$x_1c_1 +x_2c_2 \le 500c_2$$
$$y_1 \le 150 \;\;,\;\; y_2 \le 250$$
$$y_1 \le x_1 \;\;,\;\; y_2 \le x_2$$
$$x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb Z_{ \ge 0}$$

However I doubt if the inequality $x_1c_1 +x_2c_2 \le 500$ is enough, I think the question should indicate the maximum number of hats
that can be produced on a daily basis and that how many of these hats can be of the first type (at most).

Assuming the maximum number of hats that can be produced on a daily basis is $z_0$ and $z_1$ is the maximum number of produced hats of the first type, then $x_1c_1 +x_2c_2 \le 500$ should be $$x_1c_1 +x_2c_2 \le z_1c_1+(z_0-z_1)c_2$$

Comment: Your first inequality doesn't seem right.  You want an equality that models the constraints on hat production.  You have enough information so that the only variables that should appear in that equation are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  And as a sanity check, it seems clear that you want to manufacture as many hats of the second type as you can sell, since that maximizes profit per unit of manufacturing time.

Answer (score 1):

lets say the number of hat one produced is $x_1$ and hat two $x_2$. We have a time limit per day of $T$. Firstly, we know:
$$T=2a_1x_1+a_1x_2$$
$$T_{max}=500a_1$$
so it follows that:
$$2x_1+x_2\le 500\tag{1}$$
now lets say we want to sell everything we produce, production is limited by sales and so:
$$0\le x_1\le 150\tag{2.1}$$
$$0\le x_2\le 250\tag{2.2}$$
now we know how much money we make from each of the hats is given by:
$$P=8x_1+5x_2\tag{3}$$

---

What we now want to do is maximise $(1)$ whilst prioritising $x_1$.

To maximise $P$ we want $x_1$ as high as possible, so look at $x_1=150$ now we have:
$$2(150)+x_2\le 500\Rightarrow x_2\le200$$
now plug this into our equation for $P$ to get:
$$P_{max_1}=8(150)+5(200)=$2200$$

---

Now do the same but optimising $x_2$ to get:
$$x_2=250\Rightarrow 2x_1=250$$
but this doesn't work, the closest we can get is $2x_1=248\Rightarrow x_1=124\Rightarrow x_2=376$ now plug this in:
$$P_{max_2}=8(124)+5(376)=$2872$$

---

Now which of these is better?

Comment: The part I don't understand is when you claim the maximum time is given by $500a_1$

Comment: To quote "If all the hats are only of the second type, the company can produce a total of 500 hats per day" so $500\times\text{constant}\times x_2=T_{max}$ since $x_1=0$ and we are told this is the maximum production rate. It does not matter what this constant is since we know that $T_{x_1}=2T_{x_2}$

Comment: I don't understand how maximum number of hats of the second type produced per a day gives the maximum time that can be spent on producing hats

Comment: time is scaled from the number of hats. If I said I can make 12 hats a day and I work 12 hours, I can make 1 hat per hour. If I can make a coat every 30 minutes, I can make 24 coats a day...